# This isn't JSON. What is it?

Tags: json, api

Google's finance API returns something that's almost JSON, but isn't:

```
{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "0.636658815 British pounds",error: "",icc: true}
```

I'm sure this is a valid format, I'm just not sure which. What is it?

Comment: I hope you're not building something against that api since it's supposed to be shut down in 3 months...

Comment: Wait what? Do you have a source?

Comment: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to be part of the Finance API which is being shut down, and I'm not sure what else it would be categorized under. Are you sure it's being shut down?

Comment: In the article is a link to different API's that were announced as deprecated.  Click on the Finance API, and you get  https://developers.google.com/finance/

Comment: I thought it might have been part of the Finance API but looking through the documentation I can't find anything that indicates the `http://www.google.com/ig/calculator` endpoint is part of this Finance API, which is why I don't think it applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a regular JavaScript object.  It can be handled with any JavaScript parser.

Very similar to JSON, but not exactly.  If it were JSON, there would be quotes around the keys.

Comment: Any easy way to parse this with Ruby?

Comment: @Matty, Try one of these:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4940171/362536  You should be able to do little more than `eval()`, but be **very** careful if you do `eval()` this.  You don't want arbitrary code being ran.