# Parse unpleasant string in ruby to derive a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a response string that gets returned from a webservice that isn't JSON exactly, nor any other kind of hashable object, I can serialize.
I'm new to regex so I'm trying to learn how I can extract the needed pieces for my ruby code.

The string is so horrendous, I'm not sure how to go about comparing the two. I don't know much regex so that's also a hindrance. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Oof. Is that webservice actually returning *JavaScript code*? Let me look a little closer...

Comment: Is that [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?

Comment: @Biffen: Now that you mention it, probably.

Comment: For best results, you might then want to use a Ruby JavaScript parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940171/parsing-javascript-using-ruby-code. It's a little heavy, but won't get tripped up over things a regex might.

Comment: R is not equal to "laptop bag"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter passed to `partialResult` method should be valid json. You can use regex, to extract that string.

```
require 'json'
hsh = JSON.parse str.scan(/partialResult\((.*)\)/)[0][0]
#=> {"Q"=>"laptop bag", "R"=>[["laptop bag", [["Electronics", 3944]]], "laptop bags for 15.6 inch laptops", "laptop bags for women", "laptop bag 15.6", "laptop bags for 17.3 in laptops", "rolling laptop bag", "laptop bag with wheels", "laptop bag 17\""]}
```

To check for a common string

```
hsh["R"].flatten && hsh["Q"].flatten
#=> "laptop bag"
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work for all cases, could you review?

Comment: I added some details to the question, please take a look

Comment: the actual string has all these back slashes